# Will Okta create a session cookie at browser level automatically?

Tags: saml-2.0, okta, okta-api

Will Okta set a session cookie at the browser level automatically?
Am following this http://developer.okta.com/docs/examples/session_cookie guide for calling a OKTA session. I am able to see the one-time token and forming the redirect URL for the second request by adding the one time token and not able to see a `Set-Cookie` header in the response after I am redirected to the landing page. Am I missing a step? Also my application has been enabled with SAML how does it works for SAML assertions? Can anyone guide with sample example or steps to follow.

Comment: Can you be more specific when you ask how the SAML assertion works?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In most scenarios, Okta will set a session cookie *for Okta* in the browser.

For example, if you are authenticating against an Okta org named "example.okta.com", a cookie for "example.okta.com" will be set in the user's browser. This will happen if you are authenticating using OpenID Connect, an application embed link, or the (**deprecated**) `/login/sessionCookieRedirect` endpoint. However, calls made directly to the `/sessions` endpoint will not set a session cookie.

**Note:** Even though a session cookie is set *for Okta* in these scenarios, that cookie will *not* be accessible to a 3rd party application. The best way to securely validate an Okta login in a 3rd party application is to implement OpenID Connect, or SAML and set your own session cookie after validating the OpenID Connect `id_token` or SAML assertion. An alternate, but less flexible way to securely validate Okta logins is to have your backend call Okta's [`/sessions`](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/sessions.html) API endpoint, then set a session cookie on a successful call to the `/sessions` endpoint.